# Change input value depending on list order in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-ui-sortable

I asked a question yesterday which I realise didn't really make much sense, so I have made it a lot simpler hopefully now!

I have an unordered list

> ```
> <ul id="itemlist">
> <li>item 1 <input type="hidden" name="slide-order[]" value="slide[]" /></li>
> <li>item 2 <input type="hidden" name="slide-order[]" value="slide[]" /></li>
> </ul>
> ```

And this sortable script

```
$("#itemlist").sortable({
    change: function(event, ui){

         var sort = $('#itemlist').find('input');

         sort.each(function(index){
            $(this).val((index + 1));
         });
    }
});
```

What I need is for the value to always stay in order 1,2,3,4 etc when moving the list items around. So even if item 2 was moved to the top, the value would become 1.

I have tried various methods but nothing seems to be working :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$("#itemlist").sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui){
        var cnt = 1;
        $(this).children('li').each(function(){
            $(this).children('input').val("slide["+cnt+"]");
            cnt++;
        });
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d4EvC/3/)**

Comment: The order doesn't set when you drag on your demo, keeps jumping back into place?

Comment: @DamianSmith No, it changed the text. But i've updated the fiddle i think that this is what you wanted http://jsfiddle.net/d4EvC/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var sort = $('#itemlist').find('input');
sort.each(function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(this).val((index + 1));
});
```

Comment: Value doesn't change, i have set the input to text to watch for any change but nothing. :/